# Maven and Android natures not playing nice together

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven

I have an existing Android project in Eclipse which I recently decided I need to convert to a Maven enabled project so that I can build an AAR. By clicking Configure -> Convert to Maven Project, I was able to get a POM added. I then added a parent POM as well, and POM's for any dependent library projects. I added the android-maven plugin and set the packaging type to AAR.

However, once I ran Maven install, I instantly received errors. The libs, assets and res directories were expected by the android-maven plugin to be in the src/main directory. As was the AndroidManfiest. If I moved these files and fixed these errors, Maven was able to build my AAR.

Now I am left with some choices; either convert my project to the module based structure (e.g. src/main) or leave it in the Eclipse structure. Neither of these is convenient.

I believe the best possibility might be to preserve the Eclipse structure, so I can run and build my project in Eclipse. For building Maven, I believe that I am going to have to add some build scripting to essentially copy my project to another location, set the android-maven project structure, and then build and install my AAR.

Has anyone faced this situation, and what was your outcome? If no one answers, I will document my solution which involves some Ant scripting.

Comment: We hit a similar wall, but decided it was too crazy to continue with Eclipse / Maven given Android Studio / Gradle is the recommended toolset moving forward.  ("Recommended", but I don't see how you can really avoid it).  Not much help I'm afraid other than to say, we tried, gave up and moved on.

Comment: @brindy yes, I would rather not be in this situation, but unfortunately I require Eclipse because of the great NDK support.

Comment: In fact, these artifacts are being built to be used in an Android Studio project. Its easy enough to _USE_ JNI libraries in Android Studio, but they have such damn little support for building them.

Comment: android and maven works great with intellij

Comment: Why do you want to build android project in eclipse? Use maven for this.

Comment: For what it's worth, the projects yet to be migrated are in src/main format and use the com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 Android maven plugin as well as the m2e-android Eclipse plugin.  This way Eclipse still treats it as an Eclipse project, but you get the benefits of Maven too.  We never bothered trying to build AARs though.

Comment: @MariuszS Eclipse still has the best NDK support, this is the sole reason I am using it. If my builds did not use the NDK, I would be doing this in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ended up being that additional Gradle configuration was necessary with the `android-maven-plugin`. This let us specify a custom location for various directories and files in our Android project.

An example,

```
<sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.simpligility.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                 <extensions>true</extensions>
                    <configuration>
                        <attachNativeArtifacts>true</attachNativeArtifacts>
                        <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                        <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                        <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                        <androidManifestFile>${project.basedir}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                        <failOnNonStandardStructure>false</failOnNonStandardStructure>
                    </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This allowed for us to build an AAR without having to change project structure around.

Comment: `failOnNonStandardStructure` should not be necessary if you have specified all path options so the plugin knows where to look for them. In fact, omitting it will give you the benefit of Maven complaining immediately if you forgot to specify a path (or gave an incorrect one), rather than leave you with some potentially hard-to-hunt-down error.